# using letters from for loop to call attributes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to iterate through letters or words and use them to call attributes of a pandas dataframe, here is an example:

Data:

`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))`

then I need to iterate over column B and C to calculate, e.g. the mean:

`for letter in 'BC':
     df.letter.mean()`

here I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'letter'

Any idea to fix this??
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
for letter in 'BC':
    df[letter].mean()
```

`[]`enables to access a column through its name as a string: `df['B']`

Comment: exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `[]`:

```
for letter in 'BC':
     print(df[letter].mean())
```